# Area of convex n-dimensional polytope

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to calculate the surface area of an irregular N-dimensional polytope.

I have a description of this polytope both as coordinates of the vertices as as linear inequalities.

Comment: Have you considered the Delaunay-related libraries?

Comment: Will this work for dimensions D > 3?

Comment: you can compute it, but it is hard to visualize.  (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope) (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunayn.html)  you can bound it with a convex hull.  (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhulln.html) 
(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geometry/geometry.pdf)

Comment: @user17514, I am unsure of what you mean here by "area". Is your object a collection of polygons embedded in nD ? Then what you need is just the area of a nD polygon. If it is what you need, then I got a simple formula for that (and then I'll enter an answer). Or do you need to compute the (hyper)-volume inside the polytope ? (then I'm confused by the term "area")

Comment: My object is an irregular, convex N-dimensional Polytope. What I am looking for is the total sum of the areas of the sides of the polytope.